# How do I figure out what font a running urxvt is using?

Tags: fonts, resize, rxvt

I found some escape codes for changing fonts in urxvt.  I'd like to use these to dynamically change my font size.  I've seen a few plugins that do this, but they're fairly opinionated about it and usually rely on a hardcoded list of fonts to toggle through.  I'd prefer to query for the current font, change the size, and print the escape codes for that.  Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=44121](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=44121)

Comment: @FalconUA Almost what I want.  I'd like to increase or decrease based on whatever the current font is, not switch to a fixed size.  But if that's not possible this is certainly a good compromise.

Answer (score 9):

> Press Control-Shift and click a character.

A small window will appear telling you what the font is for the character you clicked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `appres` to query the font. Not sure what Linux you’re on, but if it happens to be Arch, install with: `sudo pacman -S xorg-appres`.

Example query on my system:

```
% appres urxvt |grep '\*font:' |awk '{print $2}'
-misc-orp-medium-r-*-*-12-*-75-75-*-60-iso10646-*
```

You could parse out the size info (12) from that to decide whether to increase or whatever:

```
% origsize=$(appres urxvt |grep '\*font:' |awk -F- '{print $8}')  # 12
```

You can use `printf` to increase that size, in a `my-font-changer` script, like:

```
printf "\033]710;-misc-orp-medium-r-*-*-$newsize-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*\007"
printf "\033]711;-misc-orp-bold-*-*-*-$newsize-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*\007"
printf "\033]712;-misc-orp-*-i-*-*-$newsize-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1\007"
printf "\033]713;-misc-orp-*-i-*-*-$newsize-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1\007"
```

Then you could assign a hotkey in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.keysym.M-C-1: command: my-font-changer
```

*(Most of this is untested, but you can piece it together.)*

Comment: @valadil: Were you able to get this working? Please update if you had any trouble, or accept so others will see it as a useful approach.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It outputs the font that is currently defined in `~/.Xresources`. If you open a terminal, change the font, then `xrdb ~/.Xresources`, then execute the suggested command, you'll get the font defined in `~/.Xresources`, not the font that is currently used by the current terminal.